# I just cannot get displayMousePosition to work -python

Tags: python

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/81HmQ.png)

Code:

```py
import pyautogui
pyautogui.displayMousePosition()
```

Comment: Please no images of output.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I found a fix, updating pyautogui and allowing python to view my screen.